# Why is "the `async` keyword missing" when using Tokio and Rocket?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-rocket

When compiling my Rust project, I get this error:

```
error: the `async` keyword is missing from the function declaration
  --> src/main.rs:48:7
   |
48 | async fn main() {
   |       ^^
```

My `main()` looks like:

```
#[rocket::main]
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(refresh_channel_rep());
    tokio::spawn(refresh_channel_article_count());
    tokio::spawn(remove_low_quality_articles());
    tokio::spawn(calculate_article_trend());

    let launch_result = create_server().launch().await;
    match launch_result {
        Ok(_) => println!("Rocket shut down gracefully."),
        Err(err) => println!("Rocket had an error: {}", err),
    };
}
```

Why did this happen? What should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use both `#[rocket::main]` and `#[tokio::main]`, since the first does strictly more then the second - `tokio::main` [just starts the runtime](https://docs.rs/tokio-macros/1.8.0/src/tokio_macros/entry.rs.html#386-398), `rocket::main` does the same and also [configures it](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/src/rocket/lib.rs.html#220-234) according to the Rocket configuration.

Just use the `#[rocket::main]` only, and everything should work.